# How to set parallax on the header of listview

Tags: android

I am working on app and I want to set parallax on header of listview. I have defined listview on another Xml and textview and imageview with parallax in another xml but it not working.so anyone can help me.

Secondpage.xml

```
enter code here



 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        > 
       <com.costum.android.widget.LoadMoreListView
            android:id="@+id/loadmorelistview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           />        
    </RelativeLayout>
secondpagead.xml
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:parallax_factor="1.9"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/story_page_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cover_image_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cover_image"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/cover_img" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/story_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/story_page_title_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="#cccccc"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/story_page_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="SourceSansPro-Bold"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
                        android:text="@string/stry_title"
                        android:textColor="#333"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/story_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/teller_detailWrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="3" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/teller_Img"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                             />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tellername_desig"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                            android:layout_weight="1.8"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/story_writer_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/writer_name"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"
                                android:textColor="#34495e"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/story_Date"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/clockImg"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/clock_icon" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/story_date"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                                    android:text="@string/story_create_date"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:textColor="#868686"
                                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/story_category"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:background="#e74c3c"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                            android:paddingRight="10dip"
                            android:paddingTop="5dip"
                            android:text="@string/new_story_category"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/story_meta"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/storyviews"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="6" >

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/viewimg_icon"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:src="@drawable/eye_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/stryview_count"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="542.5k"
                                android:textColor="#868686"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageimg_icon"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:src="@drawable/image_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/stryimage_count"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="25"
                                android:textColor="#868686"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/shareimg_icon"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:src="@drawable/share_icon" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/stryshare_count"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="542.5k"
                                android:textColor="#868686"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/stry_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:fontFamily="Georgia.ttf"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/stry_description_text"
                        android:textColor="#333"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout></LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```